# Xamrin Forms RelativeLayout inside Stacklayout shows empty screen

Tags: xamarin.forms, grid-layout

I am developing a cross platforms app. I am using grid in my homepage which will show four images and labels along with them. I used four stacklayout inside the grid. Each stacklayout contains releativelayout to combine image and label together.Everything works fine until I add relativelayout to the last stacklayout.What is the problem. Any helps are kindful.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
            <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="PS.DashBoard"
             BackgroundColor="White">
             <ContentPage.Content>
             <ScrollView>
             <StackLayout>
                <Image Source="logotrim.png"></Image>

                <Grid RowSpacing="0"  Margin="0,30,0,0">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />

                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="1" ColumnSpacing="80" HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                     RowSpacing="80" VerticalOptions="Center">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />


                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />


                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                        <StackLayout  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" >
                            <RelativeLayout>
                                <Image Source="time.png" WidthRequest="80"   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  />
                                <Label Text="Time" Margin="0,8,0,0"
                                                    TextColor="Black" 
                                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"  
                                                    BackgroundColor="White" 
                                                    RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1}"
                                                    RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Constant=-17}"/>

                            </RelativeLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" >
                            <RelativeLayout>
                                <Image Source="emp.png" WidthRequest="80"   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                                <Label Text="Emp" Margin="0,8,0,0"
                                                    TextColor="Black" 
                                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"  
                                                    BackgroundColor="White" 
                                                    RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1}"
                                                    RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Constant=-17}"/>

                            </RelativeLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" >
                            <RelativeLayout>

                                <Image  Source="chart.png"  WidthRequest="80"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                                <Label Text="Statistics" Margin="0,8,0,0"
                                                    TextColor="Black" 
                                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"  
                                                    BackgroundColor="White" 
                                                    RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1}"
                                                    RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Constant=-17}"/>
                            </RelativeLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" >
                            <RelativeLayout>

                                <Image  Source="info.png"  WidthRequest="80"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                                <Label Text="info" Margin="0,8,0,0"
                                                    TextColor="Black" 
                                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"  
                                                    BackgroundColor="White" 
                                                    RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1}"
                                                    RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Constant=-17}"/>
                            </RelativeLayout>
                        </StackLayout>


                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When writing in Xamarin.Forms you should always be careful not to include lots of unnecessary nested layouts as it may harm your [Performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/performance). Have a look through your code and see if you can optimize it by removing unnecessary nested layouts.

I thought I would share this with you to increase your knowledge and it smoothly brings me onto the solution to your problem. You do not need a stacklayout + nested relative layout to display what you want in this. You could achieve the desired look with a **Grid**

```
     <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" >
<!-- Here you  can put your grid columns and rows -->
<!-- on both the image and label you can assign them columns and rows with ColumnSpan / RowSpan -->
                                <Image Source="emp.png" WidthRequest="80"   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                                <Label Text="Emp" Margin="0,8,0,0"
                                                    TextColor="Black" 
                                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"  
                                                    BackgroundColor="White"/>

                        </Grid>
```

Have a look here for reference: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid

Comment: Thanks for sharing the knowledge bro..Its works now. Have a good day

Comment: No worries! Glad I could help :)